# Prove $\forall a,b \in \mathbb R, \ b \neq 0 \ \exists c \in \mathbb R : a / b = c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Prove $$\forall a,b \in \mathbb R, \ b \neq 0 \ \exists c \in \mathbb R : a / b = c$$

I've been thinking how to prove the above statement that most people assume to be true.

Should one prove there exists a bijection $\sigma_x: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $y \mapsto xy$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$ ? If yes, what statement could one use in proving this ?

The statement is not true in an arbitrary ring - an example is $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: See *Wikipedia - field* : "In abstract algebra, a *field* is a nonzero commutative ring that contains a multiplicative inverse for every nonzero element, or equivalently a ring whose nonzero elements form an abelian group under multiplication. As such it is an algebraic structure with notions of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division satisfying the appropriate abelian group equations and distributive law. The most commonly used fields are the field of *real numbers*, the field of *complex numbers*, and the field of *rational numbers*."

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the definition of the real numbers you are using (as @BrianScholl points out in his answer).

Comment: It's not *really* model dependent.

Comment: I mean in $\mathbb Z$ there is no number $c$ such that $4/5$ is defined etc.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that all definitions of the reals have a multiplication operation that guarantee the existence of inverses and closure under multiplication. That's all you need to prove this.

For any model, given such an $a$ and $b$, you are guaranteed that $\frac{1}{b}$ exists, and then $c=a\cdot\frac{1}{b}=\frac{a}{b}\in \Bbb R$.

Reassuring yourself that the defined inverse exists in the model you want to work in *would* require some work with the operation defined in the model itself.  But, abstractly speaking, as long as you believe that $\frac{1}{b}$ exists, and that the reals are closed under multiplication, and that $a\cdot \frac{1}{b}=\frac{a}{b}$, it immediately follows that $a\cdot \frac{1}{b}$ is the element you seek.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually proven by constructing $\mathbb{R}$ and proving that this construction produces a field. So, I would recommend deciding if you prefer working with special subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ called [Dedekind cuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_by_Dedekind_cuts) or if you'd rather work with [Cauchy sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_of_the_real_numbers#Construction_from_Cauchy_sequences), and going through the process of constructing $\mathbb{R}$.